# How to use Pytorch for maximum likelihood estimation with restrict optimization

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, restriction, mle

I'm studying Pytorch and I'm trying to construct a code to get the maximum likelihood estimates.

I would like to put some restrictions into optimization process to contemplate the parameters restrictions (parameter space), but It looks like in the pytorch.optim we don't have something like this.

For example, I would like to get the maximum likelihood estimates for a normal distribution with mean mu and standard deviation sigma, in which mu is a real number and sigma is a positive number.

This way, I would like to put a restriction in my code to sigma always to be a posti

Here my code:

```
##### PACKAGES
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math 

##### SAMPLE
np.random.seed(3)
sample = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=(1000, 1))

##### TENSORS
X = torch.tensor(sample, dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=False) ## X: sample
mu_ = torch.tensor(np.array([0.5]), dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True) ## mu: mean
s_ = torch.tensor(np.array([5]), dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True) ## s: standart desviation

##### OPTMIZATION METHOD: SGD
learning_rate = 0.0002
OPT_OBJ = torch.optim.SGD([mu_, s_], lr = learning_rate)

##### OPTIMAZTION METHOD
for t in range(2000):
    NLL = X.size()[0]*s_.log()+((((X-mu_)/s_ ).pow(2))/2).sum() ## negative log-likelihood
    OPT_OBJ.zero_grad()
    NLL.backward()

    if t % 100 == 0:
        print("Log_Likehood: {}; Estimate mu: {}; Estimate sigma: {}".format(NLL.data.numpy(), mu_.data.numpy(), s_.data.numpy()))

    OPT_OBJ.step()

print("True value of mu and sigma: {} e {}".format(5, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using torch.clamp() to set constraints on tensors (documentation here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clamp.html).

Otherwise, if you just want to keep the standard deviation sigma positive, the ReLU function takes the max between 0 and your input element-wise (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ReLU.html?highlight=torch%20nn%20relu#torch.nn.ReLU).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32800626)